# AA Battery Packs 54950c01 vs 59510c01

Tags: technic, power-functions, electronics

What is the difference between these two battery boxes, 54950c01:

[image: 54950c01]

and 59510c01:

[image: 59510c01]

except for the on/off button?

Which electrical connectors are compatible with each of those?

Is there a counterpart for the 54950c01 button to make it similar to the 59510c01 one?

Are these interchangeable in order to connect them to a buggy motor 5292?[image]

Comment: With regards to the switch, there's the [Plate, Modified 1x2 with Pin Hole Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11458#T=C) but the pin is over one of the studs, rather than central

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main functional difference between these is the electrical connector. The one with the red switch uses the old style 9V connection, while the one with the orange switch uses the newer Power Functions connector.

These are both the same voltage (9V), and you can mix the two systems using the [Power Functions Extension Wire (8886)](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Extension-Wire-8886).

[image: 8886]

Here's [an example showing a PF battery box powering buggy motors](http://www.sheepo.es/2015/05/tips-and-curiosities-power-functions.html):
[image: PF powered buggy motors]